# ActionView::Template::Error (index.css isn't precompiled) Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, production, precompile

I try to run my app with rails 3.2.9 alongside with passenger, and I get this message error:

```
    ActionView::Template::Error (index.css isn't precompiled):
      <head>
              <meta charset="utf-8"/>
              <title>Web Account Manager</title>
              <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "index", :media => "screen" %>
              <%= javascript_include_tag "index" %>
              <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
      </head>
  app/views/layouts/index.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_index_html_erb__115336150744996096_14575540'
```

my file production.rb:

```
    Wam::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

And not run.. I try change `config.serve_static_assets = false` to true, `config.assets.compile = false` to true.. `rake assets:clean RAILS_ENV=production` and nothing.. `rake assets:precompile` nothing.. i dont know do.

Help me ! please.. Thank!

Comment: You should immediately upgrade your app to **3.2.11**. The updates contain nothing but multiple **extremely critical security fixes**. http://weblog.rubyonrails.org

Comment: Did you try my recommendation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line to your config/application.rb file:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['index.css']
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, I added config.assets.precompile += ['index.js']

Comment: config.assets.precompile += ['*.css', '*.js'] for all views

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on heroku, heroku wants `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to be false, which take care for nut compiling the assets of included gems for example. What solved this problem for me was enabling user-env-compiling, by running:

```
 heroku labs:enable user-env-compile -a <application-name>
```

and setting `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile` to `true` in `config/application.rb`.

Hope this helps someone.

-frbl